# Multiplying the main diagonal of a matrix with a number

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

My program has to receive a number k, a 4x4 matrix and k must multiply by the main diagonal of this matrix. The output should be the input matrix, however, the main diagonal of it multiplied by k.
For exemple, I give k = 2 and the following matrix:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

The output should be:

```
2 1 1 1
1 2 1 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 1 2
```

But my program give the following output:

```
2 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Why is that? How can I do for it multiply the main diagonal and not only the first number of the matrix?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int k;
    int mult = 0;

    int matrix[4][4];
    int row, column;

    for (row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < 4; column++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }

    for(row = 0 ; row < 4 ; row++)
    {
        for(column = 0 ; column < 4 ; column++) {
            printf("%3d", matrix[row][column]);

            mult = k * matrix[row][row];
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not manipulate the matrix contents anywhere?

Comment: Where is `k` value set? Where do you set the `matrix[row][row]` new value?

Comment: Your program does not match the input and output that you claim. Please correct this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the matrix values only change the loop operation like this:

```
for(row = 0 ; row < 4 ; row++)
{
    for(column = 0 ; column < 4 ; column++) {
        if ( row == column )
            matrix[row][column] *= k;
        printf("%3d", matrix[row][column]);
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like:

```
for(row = 0 ; row < 4 ; row++)
{
    for(column = 0 ; column < 4 ; column++) {
        if(row == column)
            matrix[row][column] *= k;
        printf("%3d", matrix[row][column]);
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
```

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Ugh yea, wasn't paying attenion.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working, please check.

```
for(row=0;row<4;i++)
{
    mat[row][row]*=k;
    for(col=0;col<4;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",mat[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize the variable `k`

```
scanf("%d", &k);
```

and you didn't change the contents of your input matrix.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get the right output ,try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int k;
    int matrix[4][4];
    int row, column;
    printf("input k :\n");
    scanf("%d,"&k);
    printf("input matrix :\n");
    for (row = 0; row != 4; ++row) {
        for (column = 0; column != 4; ++column) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }

    for(row = 0 ; row != 4 ; ++row)
    {
        for(column = 0 ; column != 4 ; ++column) {
            printf("%3d",row != column ?  matrix[row][column]:k*matrix[row][cloumn]);
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To multiply the number only with selected patterns you need to give some checks(filters) so that the value gets multiplied there only.

Try the code mentioned by others as above -

```
for(row = 0 ; row < 4 ; row++)
{
    for(column = 0 ; column < 4 ; column++) {
        **if ( row == column )** //this is the filter 
            matrix[row][column] *= k;
        printf("%3d", matrix[row][column]);
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
```

for a diagonal the row and column value is always same  - 
as in your case  -

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

In a generic form it can be written as -

a00 a01 a02 a03 ....... a0n

a10 a11 a12 a13 ....... a1n

a20 a21 a22 a23........ a2n

am0 am1 am2 am3 ....... a(mn)

here the diagonal elements are - a00 ,a11,a22 ,a33 ,....a(mn) where m= n